# Converting .htaccess rule to nginx not working

Tags: nginx, rewrite

.htaccess rules:

```
   RewriteEngine On
   RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (.*)
   RewriteRule ^yon-(.*).mp4$ index.php?videodata=$1&yonlendir=true&%1 [NC]
   RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (.*)
   RewriteRule ^(.*).mp4$ index.php?videodata=$1&%1 [NC]
```

Converted to nginx:

```
   location /rigoplay {

   if ($query_string ~ "(.*)"){
   rewrite ^/yon-(.*).mp4$ /index.php?videodata=$1&yonlendir=true&%1;
   }
   if ($query_string ~ "(.*)"){
   rewrite ^/(.*).mp4$ /index.php?videodata=$1&%1;
   }
   }
```

Its however not working, throwing a 404, the URL doesn't get rewritten at all.

domain.com/rigoplay/Y0FNRDZCMGVGbGJWL2FmUjRkbm1ieGR1c2ZUaStscVRoR0h2M1F0YzV6VTI3ZS9YNkpxZVhhQ0c3dz09.mp4

Comment: What do the actual requests look like that you're trying to match?

Comment: @JCats, you should clarify a little bit more: do you have an incomming request like `/rigoplay/yon-xxxx.mp4` or like `/yon-xxxx.mp4`?

Answer (score 1):

```
location /rigoplay/ {
   rewrite ^/rigoplay/yon-(.*)\.mp4$ /rigoplay/index.php?videodata=$1&yonlendir=true last;
   rewrite ^/rigoplay/(.*)\.mp4$ /rigoplay/index.php?videodata=$1 last;
}
```

1. You don't need `if` and `%1`. Nginx automatically adds querystring to rewritten request.
2. You have to use full URI in `rewrite`.